# Javascript Eval code issue

Tags: javascript, oop, eval, user-defined-functions

I have an issue, where I want to create a 'hook' in javascript, so I created a small function to do it.

Here is my code:

```
GoogleMaps.prototype.callUserFunc = function( func, args ){
  eval('GoogleMaps.' + func + '.apply(func, args)');
}
```

The issue I have is I really don't want to use the eval() function, is there any better way of doing this?

I apologise for the noobish question, my javascript is a little on the poor side.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the `func` on the `GoogleMaps` object, or on the `.prototype` object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **square bracket notation** to access properties of an object.

example:

```
var x = {
    someProperty: 5
};

console.log(x["someProperty"]); // => 5
console.log(x.someProperty); // => 5

var y = 'someProperty';
console.log(x[y]); // => 5
```

`x["someProperty"]` is identical to `x.someProperty`.

You can use it like this.

```
GoogleMaps.prototype.callUserFunc = function( func, args ){
  GoogleMaps[func].apply(func, args);
}
```

Comment: `func` being used in `apply` makes no sense.

Comment: I agree, it should probably be `this`. I changed it to `this` at first but then changed it back to keep it functionally equivalent to his original code. Although `func.apply(func, ...` doesn't make a lot of sense, the existing code he has might rely on this behavior, and this is a different discussion.

Answer (score 3):

```
GoogleMaps.prototype.callUserFunc = function( func, args ){
  GoogleMaps[func].apply(func, args);
  //eval('GoogleMaps.' + func + '.apply(func, args)');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A true passthrough function would return the value that was returned by the function, and would be called in the context of `GoogleMaps`.

Your primary issue was not knowing that the array-access notation could be used on any object:

```
GoogleMaps.prototype.callUserFunc = function(func, args) {
    return GoogleMaps[func].apply(GoogleMaps, args);
};
```

In general, though, you'd probably be better off writing your code as:

```
GoogleMaps[func](...args...);
```

But this all assumes that `GoogleMaps` contains statically accessible functions, and isn't being used as a constructor to instantiate objects.

Without knowing how `GoogleMaps` is being used, it's possible that your passthrough function should be executing off of the object instance that `callUserFunc` is being called on:

```
GoogleMaps.prototype.callUserFunc = function(func, args) {
    return this[func].apply(this, args);
};
```

Comment: +1 This would seem to have a more sensible `thisArg` passed to `.apply`.